# onSwipe(int direction) not working

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I can't override the onSwipe() method. The error is "The method onSwipe(int) of type Adds must override or implement a supertype method". Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?. I want to navigate between activities using swipe gesture. Is there any other way to do it? If so please explain. Do I have to import any more packages?

```
package com.mahavega.qcdemo;

import com.mahavega.qcdemo.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Adds extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ads);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Adds.this, Ads2.class));
            }
        });
        ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        im1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Adds.this, Real.class));
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        switch (direction) {
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
            intent.setClass(this, Ads2.class);
            break;

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
            intent.setClass(this, Ads3.class);
            break;
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your activity should implement SimpleGestureListener to be able to recieve gesture events.

```
public class Adds extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
```

Comment: shows error "SimpleGestureListener cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: my bad,it was a typo,it should be SimpleOnGestureListener

Comment: take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html

Comment: corrected answer,the interface that you should implement is OnGestureListener,please try it and let me know

Comment: Also it could be easier to implement your own gesture listener that extends SimpleOnGestureListener if you want to listen only to a certain subset.You should definitely take a look on android developer for more info

Comment: please review my code I posted below and tell me what I have to do next

Answer (score 0):

Your error reads from the fact that Activity does not have an onSwipe(int) method. So the error is stating that you cannot override a method that has no super method.
Also as @sokie said, check out the OnGestureListener from the link he added.As for swiping gesture used to start new activities, 
when swiping left to right, override call onBackPressed (like you are going back) and on swipe right to left start new activity. Although this means you have to create the gesture listener in each of your activities.

Comment: how to get those swipe events??

Comment: you get swipe events by implementing that listener.If you have problems you should let your IDE help you when importing packages

Comment: @o3n you implement an onTouchListener to your application, then you pass the events to a gesture listener, you should have an idea after reading this post > http://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/1359802

Comment: @Raigex that is really old code,android now support proper gesture detection,and implementing the interface linked is a better aproach,as it does pretty much what is showed in that thread.

Comment: Did not know that, I was using that the last time I thought I needed gesture detection. Good to know though.

Comment: @sokie You said that its old code.. But how to do it in proper way? please give an example code